# Return any rows where column A equals a value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Suppose the sheet named Words is as such:

```
1 | Apples | Bananas
1 | Pears | Oranges
2 | Trees | Flowers
```

I would like a formula that states if `K2` contains `1` the below would form as in column A they equal 1

```
Apples | Bananas
Pears | Oranges
```

I tried
`=FILTER('Words'!A:H, 'Words'!A:A = K2)` but it was no use

Your help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you can use the FILTER function along with an ARRAYFORMULA. Here's an example formula that should work for you:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER('Words'!B:C, 'Words'!A:A = K2))
```

Make sure to replace 'Words'!B:C with the range that contains the data you want to filter (in this case, columns B and C). The formula will filter the data based on the condition 'Words'!A:A = K2, where K2 is the cell containing the value you want to compare with.

This formula will display the filtered data starting from the first row where the condition is met. Keep in mind that if you have headers in the filtered range, they will also be included in the result. If you want to exclude the headers, you can modify the formula slightly:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER('Words'!B:C, 'Words'!A:A = K2, ROW('Words'!A:A) > 1))
```

The additional condition ROW('Words'!A:A) > 1 excludes the first row from the filtered result, assuming it contains headers.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Here's my upvote. In fact, you don't need ARRAY FORMULA 